# How can we specify multiple item type in swagger array?

Tags: swagger, swagger-editor, swagger-codegen

We want to have nested array of multiple type (string, integer, float).

Below is the yaml snippet that I want to have

```
definitions:
    A:
        type: object
        required:
            - data
            - fields
        properties:
            data:
            type: array
                items:
                    type: array
                    items:
                        # I want to support number & string in this array
                        type: number | string
            fields:
                type: array
                items:
                    type: string
```

so that it can be seen as below with data

`{"data": [[1, "a", 3, 9],[2, "b", 5, 8]], fields: ["AV", "AS"]}`

Answer (score -1):

I referred this example https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md

```
definitions:
Pet:
type: object
discriminator: petType
properties:
  name:
    type: string
  petType:
    type: string
required:
- name
- petType
Cat:
description: A representation of a cat
allOf:
- $ref: '#/definitions/Pet'
- type: object
  properties:
    huntingSkill:
      type: string
      description: The measured skill for hunting
      default: lazy
      enum:
      - clueless
      - lazy
      - adventurous
      - aggressive
  required:
  - huntingSkill
Dog:
description: A representation of a dog
allOf:
- $ref: '#/definitions/Pet'
- type: object
  properties:
    packSize:
      type: integer
      format: int32
      description: the size of the pack the dog is from
      default: 0
      minimum: 0
  required:
  - packSize
```

Comment: I think allOf, anyOf and oneOf are supported in OpenAPI 3.0 and not 2.0